# Architecture for dynamic tables to render reports/graph

Tags: architecture, reporting

I am using a SQL server database for storing data. I have created some dynamic tables those will store the per-calculated values. Dynamically created tables may have 2 columns, 3 columns or even more. Based on the filter selection i will identify the dynamic table to get the per-calculated result and render tabular report or graph in the screen (HTML). Creation of tables and populating values will be call at some given time using the SQL Job.

Anyone can suggest what architecture should I use for my application? MVC or ASP.NET?

Thanks,

Comment: MVC and ASP.NET are not architectures. The first is a pattern and the second a framework and in fact you can use both

Answer (score 0):

You could use either but also look at [ASP.Net Dynamic Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488545%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) as it has features you might find save you time.